# Insert specific image every 10 images in a php slideshow

Tags: php, jquery, loops, foreach, slideshow

I made a simple php loop that loads all the images from a directory and puts them in a jQuery Slideshow. Here's the php code:

```
 <?php
function scd($dir){$files=scandir($dir);sort($files);reset($files);return $files;}

$output='<script>$.backstretch([';
$dir='images';
$files=scd($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
    if($file==='.'||$file==='..'){continue;}
        $output.='"'.$dir.'/'.$file.'"
    , ';
}
echo $output.'  ], {duration: 10000, fade: 1000});</script>';
?>
```

I'd like to insert a specific image from an external directory (i.e. an advertisement for my company) every 10 slides but I have no clue on how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter of some sort to keep track of how many images you've displayed and display the advertisement when counter%10 ==0

```
$counter = 1
foreach($files as $file){
    if($file==='.'||$file==='..'){continue;}
    if($counter%10 == 0)
         $output .= //ADVERTISEMENT LINK
    $output.='"'.$dir.'/'.$file.'", ';
    $counter++
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't get it working :/ I get a blank page.

Will my code be:

  [code]<?php
function scd($dir){$files=scandir($dir);sort($files);reset($files);return $files;}

$output='<script>$.backstretch([';
$dir='images';
$files=scd($dir);
$counter = 1
foreach($files as $file){
    if($file==='.'||$file==='..'){continue;}
    if($counter%10 == 0)
         $output = '"img/ad.jpg", ';
    else
         $output.='"'.$dir.'/'.$file.'", ';
    counter++
}
echo $output.'  ], {duration: 10000, fade: 1000});</script>';
?>[/code]

Comment: My bad, I left out a `$` on the second to last line, should be `$counter++` not `counter++`

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work :/ I Keep getting a blank page. I'm not good (at all) at php :/

Comment: I got your code working but there's still a problem:
If there's 10 images, it only displays the ad, not the 10 images then mine :/

`$counter = 1;
foreach($files as $file){
    if($file==='.'||$file==='..'){continue;}
    if($counter %10 == 0)
         $output = '"URL_OF_MY_AD", ';
    else
         $output.='"'.$dir.'/'.$file.'", ';
    $counter++;
}
echo $output.'  ], {duration: 10000, fade: 1000});</script>';
`

Comment: @user3783235 oh, I just realized your outputting and appending to an array. Remove the `else` so it also adds your image instead of skipping every 10th image, and change `$output = '"URL_OF_MY_AD", ` to be `$output .= '"URL_OF_MY_AD", '`, so it correctly appends the advertisement link into your array

Comment: Thanks ! it _almost_ works as expected :D now, my ad displays after the 10th slide but not after every multiple of 10 (20,30,40 ...). How may I do it ? Thanks a lot for your precious help :) !!

Comment: @user3783235 the modulo should trigger every 10th slide, does your slideshow filter duplicates?

Comment: to be honest I don't know what my slideshow filter is .. the html output with your code set on if($counter%2 == 0):

`<script>$.backstretch(["images/1403301738-ciroc.jpg", "http://img.url.com/myad.jpg", "images/1403304017-tanqueray.jpg", "images/1403305261-summer.jpg",   ], {duration: 10000, fade: 1000});</script>`